# Symfony Upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3 routing error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I just started to upgrade my project from 2.2 to the newly released 2.3, and after a while I managed to get it work, but there is a little problem in dev environment.
From the routing_dev.yml it reads only the first entry, and if the first is the profiler, for the route / it will found the profiler default route and don't go forward to read in the main route file, but if I change the order and the main router is the first, then the profiler doesn't apply so I don't have the debug toolbar.

My routing_dev.yml:

```
    _main:
    resource: routing.yml

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler
```

Config_dev.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: false
    profiler:
      only_exceptions: false
      enabled:         true

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Cache was cleared, deleted and vendors was deleted and updated multiple times.

Comment: Do you still have _configurator in routing_dev.yml?

Comment: no, the one more thing is assetic with resource:. , but this problem also stands for normal routing.yml, if I don't put to the first place my bundle's routing, instead FOS is before, then a FOS route will be matched

Comment: Did you take _configurator out?  The reason I am asking is that I suspect that maybe you updated from an even earlier version of Symfony (2.1.?) and that you never updated the config files.  Consider pulling down an empty 2.3.0 project and diff'ing the config files.

Comment: Actually I started the upgrade from 2.0.12 2 weeks a go and finished a week ago and saw that 2.3 will be out, so when it came out officially I stated to work on it. And I just checked the original config.yml from 2.0.12 version and i didn't had _configurator there at all.

Comment: Not sure exactly when _configurator was added but that is what raised the possibility that your config files were out of date.  You might consider starting with a fresh 2.3.0 install and add your routes.  Do keep in mind that the profile toolbar will only be shown if a full html page is generated.

Comment: But what is this _configurator? I doesn't find anything like that in 2.3 base files.